# Error [TypeError]: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, disqus

I am experimenting with a progam called Disqus to add comments section on next.js react.js blog. Not showing any errors but when I try to render the code I get error: "Error [TypeError]: Super expression must either be null or a function"

```
"use client"
import { DiscussionEmbed } from "disqus-react"
import { Post } from "@/app/lib/interface"
import React from "react"

const DisqusComments = ({Post}) => {
    const disqusShortname = "weeksagenda"  
    const disqusConfig = {
      url: "https://localhost:3000/post/[slug]",
      identifier: Post.url,// Single post id
      title: Post.title // Single post title
    }  
    console.log (disqusShortname, disqusConfig)
    return (
      <div>
        <DiscussionEmbed
          shortname={disqusShortname}
          config={disqusConfig}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }

export default DisqusComments;
```

I have researched the error extensively. No errors in syntax from what I observe. Not using super constructor. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably want `({Post})` ->`({post: Post})` and use `post` as your variable

Comment: Are you using the app or pages router? This error typically comes from importing certain class based components (hence why it's mentioning `super`). It generally goes away by adding the `use client` directive (which I see you've added already). As a matter of fact, I tried to import `DiscussionEmbed` on my own computer and using `use client` was enough to get rid of that error. Something you can try to do as well is [dynamically import](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#with-no-ssr) `DiscussionEmbed`.